# RUBY getting user input, reading a file and using ERB to copy it to another file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right, so lets preface this with that I'm very much still learning here.

What I have is a file, in which I've put a bunch of tags like so:

```
stuff stuff stuff <%= #{username} %> stuff stuff
```

then in my .rb I have a bunch of inputs like so:

```
puts "Enter your username: "
username = gets.chomp
```

Now, I want to read my template and in a new file replace all the
    <%= #{username} %> with the actual input.

I am getting varied results in my attempts to sort this out on my own but I'm thinking its something like this:

```
data = File.read('template/userinfo.txt')
data = ERB.new(File.write('yourinfo.txt', 'w'))
```

Any kind soul out here that can point me in the right direction?

(the file gets created, but the tags remain)

Comment: I've seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422564/inserting-variables-into-erb-from-txt-file but that doesn't show me how I get it into another file, the file gets created but the tags remain unfilled :(

Comment: Have you looked at [the example from the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#class-ERB-label-Examples)? As far as I can tell, this is precisely what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

As it stated in the very first example of the documentation on [`ERB`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html), one should call `ERB#result`:

```
username = 'ohmni'
template = ERB.new(File.read('template/userinfo.txt'))
File.write('yourinfo.txt', template.result(binding))
```

Comment: Thank you! I confused myself with using the template.result(binding)) in my different tries and hurt my little brainy-brain :(